# Always some test cases getting jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: jasmine, protractor, angular6

I am going to create end to end(e2e) test using protractor with jasmine and angular 6. I have written some test cases almost 10 cases. That's all working fine, but always some cases become fails. And its failed because of jasmine timeout. I have configure timeout value like below. But I am not getting consistant result. sometimes a test cases is success but at next run it will goes to success or fail. I have searched on google but I have not found any useful solution.

I have defined some common properties for wait

```
  waitForElement(element: ElementFinder){
      browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
      browser.wait(() => element.isPresent(), 100000, 'timeout: ');
  }

  waitForUrl(url: string){
      browser.wait(() => protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains(url), 100000, 'timeout')
  }
```

And protractor.conf.js file I have defined that

```
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000,
        print: function () {
        }
    }
```

I am getting below error

```
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.12 (220b19a666554bdcac56dff9ffd44c300842c933-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#83}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution:

I have configured waiting timeout 100000 ms for individual element find where whole script timeout was 20000 ms. So I have follow below process:

Keep full spec timeout below than sum of all elements find timeouts. I have configured **defaultTimeoutInterval** at **jasmineNodeOpts** greater than sum of value for all test cases timeout. And then add a large value to **allScriptsTimeout**: 2000000 inside of export.config. Its resolved my problem.

NB: I gave this answer because I think it may help others who will face this kind of problem.

Comment: Cool it worked for you, but why would you want to wait more than half an hour? Timeouts should be reasonable, line no more than 10 mins (I always use 5 mins, which is still a lot)

Comment: Its just an example. You should use your one.